# Separating email addresses

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I would like to know how to separate email addresses in the following code:

```
With OutApp.CreateItem(0)
If cel.Value <> "" Then
.To = cel.Value
.CC = cel.Offset(0, 10).Value & cel.Offset(0, 11).Value
.Body = strbody & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Signature
```

In the CC field when the macro is run it does populate the fields but like this:
CC: will@me.comother@mail.com and it should be like this CC: will@me.com; other@mail.com

Any ideas on how to solve this?
I have already tried: `cel.Offset(0, 10).Value & ";" & cel.Offset(0, 11).Value` but no luck

Comment: try this `cel.Offset(0, 10).Value & ";  " & cel.Offset(0, 11).Value`

Comment: Generate a recepients string of email addresses and set .CC = recepients

Comment: @simoco It didn't separate the email addresses

Comment: @IrfanShaikh the recipients are on two columns M and N

Comment: @William, try to add `MsgBox cel.Offset(0, 10).Value & "; " & cel.Offset(0, 11).Value` just before line `.CC = ...`. What you will get?

Comment: @simoco a message box pops up with both emails but only adds the first one to the CC line

Comment: try to use this one: `cel.Offset(0, 10).Value & ", " & cel.Offset(0, 11).Value`

Comment: that does separate the emails but does not find them in Check names

Comment: @simoco hey its fixed like this `cel.Offset(0, 10).Value & " ; " & cel.Offset(0, 11).Value` and its working now

Comment: @simoco Thanks for the Input and once again for your time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed like this `cel.Offset(0, 10).Value & " ; " & cel.Offset(0, 11).Value` and its working now

Answer (score 0):

Consider something more dynamic:

```
join(worksheetfunction.Transpose(range("A1:A4")),";")
```

This way you can programatically change the range and it will just join as many rows as you have. The method you have chosen means there must always be 2 people (and ONLY 2 people) to CC.

Range("A1:A4") gets the range of data, Transpose will swap it from a top to bottom orientation to a left to right scenario (making it an array), the Join function joins all elements of an array using the supplied delimiter (in this case ";")